# how signalR manage concurrent user updates

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

can anyone tell me please, how SIGNALR manage consurrent user updates. What happened when user click "send" button at a same time. How SIGNALR identify which call is associated to which client.

Comment: Any chance you give some feedback on the answers you receive to your questions? You hardly give any feedback to answers you receive. This is a community where some people ask questions and look forward to answers, and some others *put effort* and answer, expecting *feedback* (acceptance, votes, comments, whatever). You shouldn't just *take*, but also *give*, or people might well stop trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Each single connection has a unique `connectionId` which is transmitted across server and clients usually at each call, so there is no issue with that. The server would receive 2 parallel calls but each one will be correctly associated to the right client through the exchanged `connectionId`. You should check the official documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#terminology).